# Equals Operator not working within if statement

Tags: java, arrays, equals

For some reason, my program won't allow the if statement if (arr == arr[i]), saying that the == operator cannot be applied to double[], double. However, it works on my friends program. Why doesn't it work, and how I can fix it? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What length (in a whole number) would you like the array to be? ");
        int arraySize = sc.nextInt();

        double[] arr = new double[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            int requiredInput = arraySize - i;
            System.out.println("Please enter " + requiredInput + " more 'double' numbers.");
            arr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println("What 'double' would you like to find the first and last indexes of?");
        double searchIndex = sc.nextDouble();

        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++) {
            if (arr == arr[i]) {

            }
        }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

      
    }
}
```

Comment: It will definitely not work "on my friends program". What do you expect `arr == arr[i]` to do? How would a comparison of an `array` to a `double` work?

Comment: As an analogy, you're trying to test if a basket of apples is the same thing as one of the apples in the basket.  Clearly they are not the same thing.  Can you define in plain words what you expect that `if` condition to check?

Comment: Basically, the point of the program is to find the first location a number appears within an array, and the last location it appears, or if at all. here is an update version: boolean indexPresent = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++) {
            if (arr == arr[i]) {
                indexPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

Comment: Then just check for the searchIndex?

Comment: @CactusCoder how would I do that? I'm new to java and the only way I know how is using the contains method but that does not work for arrays.

Comment: @ChrisJones `if (searchIndex == arr[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is what you are trying to do.  Take a double value from the console and find the index of that double in an array of doubles.  To do this, you need to save the index.

```
int index = -1;
System.out.println("What 'double' would you like to find the first and last indexes of?");
double doubleToFind = sc.nextDouble();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (doubleToFind == arr[i]) {
         index = i;  // save the index (location in the array)
         break;
    }
}
```

Once the loop is done, you can do something like this.

```
if (index == -1) {
    System.out.println("Value not found");
} else {
    System.out.println(doubleToFind + " is at index " + index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `searchIndex` is the double value to search, then your `if()` should be as follows.

```
if (arr[i] == searchIndex) {
     indexPresent = true;
     break;
}
```